# Fetch from two APIs in loop and combine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to do what I thought would be pretty straightforward, but is turning out to be pretty hard. Essentially what I want to do is when loading the page, loop through an array of IDs, make a call to two APIs for each ID, merge the responses together for each ID, and save that to a React state variable `itemList`.

This is the code I have so far. The two `getInfo()` and `getOtherInfo()` functions are doing a basic JavaScript Fetch and are returning a Promise and then the decoded JSON data asynchronously no problem. I can even display the returned data on the page as it gets loaded, so that part works fine.

```
useEffect(() => {
  idList.forEach((id) => {
    getInfo(id)
      .then((response) => {
        getOtherInfo(id).then((otherReponse) => {
          response.otherInfo = otherResponse;
        });
        setItemList((itemList) => [...itemList, response]);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("Loading failed: " + error));
  });
}, []);
```

I know that the nested `.then()` is wrong, as it's trying to add response data to a potentially unresolved Promise, but it's my first time using React Hooks and the Fetch API so I'm not sure what the *right* way to do it is. I've found a couple other similar questions, but they don't seem to deal with joining the data together after it gets returned from the two APIs.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: You should iterate and generate an array of Promises. And then pass this promise array in Promise.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that the nested .then() is wrong, as it's trying to add response data to a potentially unresolved Promise

If you need the resolved values of `response` and `otherResponse` before continuing, it's better to put the logic needed inside the inner `then()` continuation. This is what you've done when setting `response.otherInfo = otherResponse`, but I think the `setItemList` call should also be inside that continuation.

```
useEffect(() => {
  idList.forEach((id) => {
    getInfo(id)
      .then((response) => {
        getOtherInfo(id).then((otherReponse) => {
          response.otherInfo = otherResponse;
          setItemList((itemList) => [...itemList, response]);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("Loading failed: " + error));
  });
}, []);
```

If the request to `getOtherInfo` is not dependent on the outcome of `getInfo`, then it may be beneficial to execute those requests concurrently using `Promise.all`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  idList.forEach((id) => {
    Promise.all([getInfo(id), getOtherInfo(id)])
      .then(([response, otherResponse]) => {
        response.otherInfo = otherResponse;
        setItemList((itemList) => [...itemList, response]);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("Loading failed: " + error));
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I thought I was on completely the wrong track so nice to know it was a small error setting `.otherInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var promiseArr = [];    
idList.forEach((id) => {
  promiseArr.push(getInfo(id));
    promiseArr.push(getOtherInfo(id));
});

Promise.all(promiseArr).then((resp) => {
   console.log(resp);
}).catch((error) => console.log("Loading failed: " + error));
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. I'm still not sure how to join the data together though - once it returns it's just a flat array. It needs to end up in the structure `info = {name:"xyz", otherInfo:{details:"abc"}}`

Comment: Pushing all promises into a single array will exhibit different behaviour to the original code, as  the resulting promise will only be resolved when _all_ the requests are resolved. The original code incrementally appends the state, which means that the interface can be updated with partial results as they are available.